# PHP variable variables with mysql resultset

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql table which has a id column (sid) that can be dynamically added to. Now I am doing a query to get count of all entries grouped into each of these sid's like so:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sid = 71, 1, 0)) as count71,
SUM(IF(sid = 72, 1, 0)) as count72,
SUM(IF(sid = 75, 1, 0)) as count75,
SUM(IF(sid = 81, 1, 0)) as count85
FROM `table`
WHERE userid=44;
```

Note that all the SUM fields are created dynamically and I don't know what the actual sid's are. Now question is how do I loop through the resultset for each of the counts using PHP's variable variables? I've tried this but doesn't work.

```
$count_var = "rs['count71']"
$$count_var // holds number of entries where sid is 71;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest this instead:

```
select sid, count(*) from `table` where userid = 44 group by sid ;
```

Comment: Doh! that would solve my problem indeed. But just for knowledge's sake, how would I achieve the above if I were to design the MySQL query as it is above?

Comment: @user1181950: One way would be to first perform ``SELECT DISTINCT sid FROM `table` `` then, in PHP, loop over the results constructing your SQL as you had been above.

Comment: I believe you are asking about this: `$sid = 71; $count_of_71 = $rs["count" . $sid];`. No need to use eval here.

Comment: ok my use case above is quite bad; I apologize. I am using a framework, and it returns the resultset as an array of classes with the fields as memebers, so I'd have to access it as $rs[0]->count71. In that case, is eval the only option?

Comment: You can then do: `$sid = 71; $rs[0]->{"count" . $sid};`

Comment: oh cool, did not know i could do that, definitely helpful to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$count_var = "rs['count71']";
echo eval('return $'. $count_var . ';');
```

but of course @troelskn's answer is probably the best solution for what you want

Comment: Yes but this is definitely helpful for my knowledge. Thanks!